# PHP MSSQL weekly event

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a table of records. The user is allowed to enter data based on the date the event happened. The table becomes something like this:

```
ID  Date        Name      Hrs
1   2016-03-01  Username   8    
2   2016-03-02  Username   8    
3   2016-03-03  Username   9    
4   2016-03-04  Username   10       
…               
31  2016-03-31  Username   8
```

1. I want to be able to display date (even without records) that the user didn't enter.
2. I also want to display all the records in the table breaking them into weeks. Something like this:

   `Day   Date        Name      Hrs`

   ```
   Mon 2016-03-01  Username   8    
   Tue 2016-03-02  Username   8    
   Wed 2016-03-03  Username   9    
   Thu 2016-03-04  Username   10   
   Fri 2016-03-05  Username   10
   Sat 2016-03-06  -
   Sun 2016-03-07  Username   10

   Mon 2016-03-08  Username   8    
   Tue 2016-03-09  -
   Wed 2016-03-10  -   
   Thu 2016-03-11  -   
   Fri 2016-03-12  Username   10
   Sat 2016-03-13  -
   Sun 2016-03-15  Username   10

   ...
   ...
   ...

   Mon 2016-03-30  Username   8    
   Tue 2016-03-31  Username   8
   ```

Below is my code:

```
<?php

...Connection to DB...

$query="SELECT *
        FROM  Table_I
        ORDER BY DATEPART(wk,date) as wk
       ";

$params = array($_REQUEST['query']);
$results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));

if($results===false)
 { die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) ); }

$rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($results);
$array = array();

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    { 
      $array[] = $row;

    }
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<table border="1">

<?php

        for($a=0; $a<$rows; $a++)
        {       
        echo '<tr><td>'.$array[$a]['wk'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.date("l", strtotime($array[$a]['date'])).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.date('d M Y', strtotime(strip_tags($array[$a]['date']))). "</td>";
        echo '<td>'.strip_tags($array[$a]['name'])."</td>";
        echo '<td>'.strip_tags($array[$a]['hrs'])."</td>";

        }

</body>
</html>
```

It prints alright but doesn't include dates the user didn't enter and doesn't break it down into each week. I'm very new to programming but it's fun though.

Please, help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: @FLICKER Sql-server 2008

Comment: @Uday can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with below query. I believe you can get what you want by some minor changes.

Below query gives you missing dates.

```
;WITH numbers AS 
( 
 SELECT cast('2016-03-01' as date) AS num
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT dateadd(day, 1, num)
   FROM numbers  
     WHERE num < '2016-03-31'
) 
select num as MissingDate
from numbers
  left join yourEventTable on yourEventTable.Dt = numbers.num
where ID is null
```

using above query, you can group by week number:

```
;WITH numbers AS 
( 
 SELECT cast('2016-03-01' as date) AS num 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT dateadd(day, 1, num) FROM numbers  
     WHERE num < '2016-03-31'
) 
, dys as (
select num 
from numbers
)
select datepart(week, num), *
from dys 
  left join #events on #events.Dt = dys.num
```

with below sample,

Comment: Thanks for your response, @FLICKER.

Don't be mad, but how do I integrate this into my code?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think you just need to execute the query and loop on it and render on html as you already is doing that.

Comment: First run both queries and see the result, then you'll figure out how you can use it

Comment: Thanks a again, @FLICKER.

The table name isn't included in the query you gave me. How would it know what I'm trying to do?